can't browse server for videos in Django Rest Framework project using CKEditor in admin panel
I use CKEditor for my django project to write Articles rich text. I easily can upload images to the server and next time select them by browsing server like this (by click on Embed Image button):
enter image description here
enter image description here
But the problem is when I choose a video that I uploaded before I can't use that and Embed Image button doesn't appears. (just also IDM shows a page to start download video). and I just see a loading icon.
enter image description here
I also have to say that I'm using HTML5Video CKEditor plugin for the approach.
my CKEditor configs in settings.py :
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR)

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR/'media'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH= 'uploads/'
# MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')

STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path. join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),


CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/'
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default':{
    'toolbar': 'full',
    'removePlugins':'exportpdf',
    'extraPlugins': ','.join([
        'codesnippet', 'widget', 'html5video', 'uploadimage'
        ])
}
}

I wanted to use CKFinder in my DRF project but I didn't find any guideline to do that.
